# QCustomPlot fills in lines that connect

Tags: c++, qt, qcustomplot

Using the QCustomPlot add on for QT. I am having to plot points which may are not linear so the graph could look something like this [image]

how ever this is the result

[image]

but this is what shows up

using this code

```
    plotter->addGraph();
    plotter->graph(0)->setData(xVector, yVector);
    plotter->xAxis->setLabel("X");
    plotter->yAxis->setLabel("Y");
    plotter->xAxis->setRange(x_data_range_min x_data_range_max);
    plotter->yAxis->setRange(y_data_range_min, y_data_range_max);
    plotter->replot();
    plotter->saveJpg("test.jpg");
    plotter->close();
```

now I found a partial fix, by adding this option to get ride of the connected lines and only show the points,

```
    plotter->graph(0)->setLineStyle((QCPGraph::LineStyle)QCPGraph::lsNone);
    plotter->graph()->setScatterStyle(QCPScatterStyle(QCPScatterStyle::ssDisc , 3));
```

and the result is this but has a problem, it leaves a kinda bold spot which I can't have

[image]

so this is a semi-solution. So I went ahead and added what A. Sarid mentioned in the replys below. I think the first graph may plot fine, but any other graph after it looks like this

[image]

so I am not sure which solution can make only the dots connect in the order in which they are received from the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had the same problem few days ago.
You need to use [QCPCurve Class](http://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCPCurve.html) instead of Graph. Here is a small example of how to do it:

```
this->newCurve = new QCPCurve(ui->customPlot->xAxis, ui->customPlot->yAxis);
ui->customPlot->addPlottable(this->newCurve);
```

And then you can use it the same way you use graph, for example:

```
this->newCurve->setData(x, y);
```

Comment: not working, the data is coming out very odd, it its adding so many extra lines and looks like it is also producing double values, not sure why

Comment: @Tanner it will be helpful if you'll add relevant parts from your code and give some background of what you are trying to plot.

Comment: I know sorry I was about to edit my comment, ok so my program reads in multiple files and plots them. Doing what you said to do, I am not sure if its plotting points from previous graphs since it should not since the data gets reset per method call, this is also how i been doing it with the qcustomplot object alone. anyways doing what you said, the everything after the first graph looks like this http://imgur.com/NUGEMq6 and i am trying to draw something like this http://imgur.com/6FAbv7L based off the points, i will update original post right now

Comment: make sure that the data in your x, y vectors are first of all syncronized and second, in the right order you want them to be. QCPCurve uses another coordinate _t_ which defines the order of the points, maybe the order you insert the data to the plot is not really the order you want it to be.

Comment: the order should be fine, the data given to me is out of my control, it is the order in which someone is drawing the lines, as for the t  value, not sure how to use it, but i can look up the documentation and try to figure it out

Comment: I think I got it, i had to use the curve like you said, but every loop for each graph I had to clear the curve. :) thank you A Sarid